# Translations from English to Language of Predicate Logic (PL)

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, logic-translation

I have to some translations. Here is what I need to translate and what I have so far.

1. Every philosopher respects some self-respecting logician.
   Let "x" denote philosophers and "y" denote logicians. And let "R" be the respecting relation.

$\forall x \exists y (Rxy \rightarrow Ryy)$

2. There is someone that loves everyone who respects themselves.
   Let "R" be the respecting relation and let "L" be the loving relation.

$\exists x \forall y (Lxy \land Ryy)$

I also think that the English sentence is tantamount to saying that there is some x s.t. x loves everyone and if x loves everyone then everyone loves themselves, so I translated that as...

$\exists x ((\forall y)Lxy \land (\forall yLxy \rightarrow Ryy))$

3. Everyone who loves everyone else also loves everyone who is loved by someone else.
   $\forall x (\exists y Lxy \land \forall y Ly \rightarrow \exists z(Lzx \land y \neq z))$

Does anyone see where I've gone wrong? Are there any tips about how to proceed? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For 1: You can't just say $x$ are philosophers and $y$ are logicians: *every* variable you use will be quantified over the *whole* domain ... which will have to include both philosophers and logicians.

So, what you need to do is to use *predicates* for the philosophers and logicians, e.g. $P(x):$ '$x$ is a philosopher' and $L(x):$ '$x$ is a logician'

OK, give that one another try.

For 2., there is a conditional missing. Right now, it ends up saying: 'there is someone x for which it is true that everyone y respects themselves and that first person x will love y' ... which implies, among other things, that everyone definitely respects themselves!  That is a far stronger statement than the original English sentence.   Paraphrase it as: 'there is some person x such that for every person y: *if* y respects themselves, then x will love y'

OK, give that one another try as well.

For 3, you'll first need to fix your parentheses before I'll comment ..

Comment: I've changed 1 to something like this: $\forall x (\exists y Ly \land Ryy \rightarrow Rxy)$. My thought that the sentence was tantamount to saying that for all x if x respects some y that is a logician that also respects itself then x respects that y.

Comment: @Rusty Make sure to say that x is a philosopher

Comment: Oh god, so my conditional's antecedent now looks like a conjunction:   $\forall x (Px \land \exists y(Ly \land Ryy) \rightarrow Rxy)$

Comment: And as per your suggestion for 2, I'm getting $\exists x (\forall yLxy \land (Ryy \rightarrow Lxy)$ which says, I think, "there is some x s.t. x is in love with every y and if y respects itself then y then x loves y.

Comment: OK, for 1: The claim is about philosophers, so it will be of the form $\forall x (P(x) \rightarrow ...)$.  What you *say about* those philosophers goes in the consequent, so that is the part where you say that they respect some self-respecting logician .. try again.

Comment: Your new 2 still has the problem that it makes a claim about everyone ..now it says (among other things) that someone loves everyone! And please pay attention to those parentheses ... and make sure all variables are quantified, i.e. occur within the scope of the quantifier for that variable.

Comment: Sorry, I have a a really hard time with this stuff as you know by now. 
Given your advice for 1, it seems like I just need to put an existential quantifier in there: $\forall x (P(x) \rightarrow \exists y (Rxy \land Ryy))$.

Comment: And for 2 I now have $\exists (Lxy \land \forall y(Lxy \rightarrow Ryy))$--there is some x that is in love with y and for any y that x loves then that y respects itself?

Comment: @Rusty Don't apologize :)  OK, your 1 is now correct! (though it wasn't just matter of getting an existential in there, but *where* to put it)

Comment: @Rusty For your last 2 ... you now have the first y in the first Rxy as a free variable. ... fortunately, there is no need for that whole Rxy in the first place, as you are using one later on in the second.   But also think of the placement of the $Ryy$ ... that  should be in the antecedent: *if* y is self-respecting, *then* x will love y.

Comment: Do I not need to put a monadic predicate into #1 for "is a logician"?

Comment: @Rusty  Oh my! Yes, of course!  See, you're getting better at this; you're correcting me now! :)

Comment: Suppose that #2 says $\exists x (Lxy \land \forall y (Ryy \rightarrow Lxy))$ Is this right? I feel like I need the Lxy because the original $\exists x$ ranges over a conjunction.

Comment: @Rusty Oh, I see ... No, just because you have a $\exists$ does not mean you have to have a conjunction in there. So really, remove that term and you're good.

Comment: That's troubling; I've been told that whatever I'm translating into English if the quantifier with the widest-scope is an $\exists$ then it's going to range over a conjunction, and if the quantifier with the widest scope is a $\forall$ it will range over a conditional.

Comment: @Rusty That's what *often* happens, yes, but certainly not always. Here is one of those exceptions.  Or, maybe better put: you don;t get a conjunction here because you don;t really predicate something about the x for the subject term. For example, if 2 would have said: 'There is some philosopher who loves everyone who respects themselves, then we would have gotten: $\exists x (Px \land \forall y (Ryy \rightarrow Rxy))$ and now you see the $\land$ appearing again.

Comment: What are my big issues with #3? (I think the parentheses are ok now?)

Comment: I've changed my 3 to get something like this: 
$\forall x ((\forall y (x\neq y \rightarrow Lxy) \rightarrow \exists ((z \neq w \rightarrow Lzw) \rightarrow Lxz)))$ thoughts?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68239/discussion-on-answer-by-bram28-translations-from-english-to-language-of-predicat).